# speed up python apply row wise functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, apply

I am working on one of the data cleansing project, I have to clean multiple fields of a pandas data frame as part of it. Mostly I am writing regular expressions and simple functions. Examples below,

```
def func1(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.replace(' ', '')
    if len(s) > 0 and s != '0':
        if s.isalpha() and len(s) < 2:
            return s

def func2(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.replace(' ', '')
    s = s.strip(whitespace+','+'-'+'/'+'\\')
    if s != '0':
        if s.isalnum() or s.isdigit():
            return s

def func3(s):
    s = str(s)
    if s.isdigit() and s != '0':
        return s
    else:
        return None

def func4(s):
    if str(s['j']).isalpha() and str(s['k']).isdigit() and s['l'] is none:
        return s['k']
```

And calling them like this.

```
x['a'] = x['b'].apply(lambda x: func1(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
x['c'] = x['d'].apply(lambda x: func2(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
x['e'] = x['f'].apply(lambda x: func3(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
x['g'] = x.apply(lambda x: func4(x), axis = 1)
```

Everything is fine here, however I have written nearly 50 such functions like this and my dataset has more than 10 million records. Script runs for hours, If my understanding is correct, the functions are called row wise, so each function is called as many times as the rows and its taking long time to process this. Is there a way to optimise this? How can I approach this in a better way? May be not through apply function? Thanks.

Sample dataset:-

```
        Name                               f    j    b
339043  Moir Point RD                      3    0   
21880   Fisher-Point Drive Freemans Ba     6    0   
457170  Whakamoenga Point                 29    0   
318399  Motukaraka Point RD                0    0   
274047  Apirana Avenue Point England     360    0   366
207588  Hobsonville Point RD             127    0   
747136  Dog Point RD                     130    0   
325704  Aroha Road Te Arai Point          36    0   
291888  One Tree Point RD                960    0   
207954  Hobsonville Point RD             160    0   205D
248410  Huia Road Point Chevalier        106    0
```

Comment: I think the application of 50 functions is the issue. Is there really no better way to manipulate the data than applying 50 individual functions?

Comment: No, since it is a data cleaning work, I need to capture and handle different possible patterns on each field. Though I am clubbing as much as possible if anything is related.

Comment: Try `multiprocessing` module and run your job in as many threads as your processor has.

Comment: To be clear, your functions return `None` if the condition is not met. Is this your intention?

Comment: Yeah. thats right.

Comment: Can you give some sample input? Like 5 or so rows? I'd like to give an answer but I want to make sure it works on your sample data.

Comment: sorry about it. :( I can't reveal it here. Its confidential. I know I can't say this after asking help here. But I don't have other choice.

Comment: So you can't make up a DataFrame with words like "banana" and "apple" and random numbers that I can copy and paste? I just need something that works with the sample code that is similar to your data. I'm trying to help *for free*, please throw me a bone.

Comment: Ha ha.. Yeah I understand that. I am already making a sample set now. Will give it in minutes. :) Thanks by the way.

Comment: @SethMMorton Updated the sample data here for you.

Comment: What about columns j, k, and l?

Comment: Hey, I am not trying to optimise these functions exactly. I am approaching these problems with multiple functions and calling apply function for each scenario, looking for alternatively approach this problem to optimise the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should avoid calling `.apply` on a `DataFrame`.  This is really what is getting you.  Under the hood, it is creating a new `Series` for each row in the `DataFrame` and sends that to the function passed to `.apply`. Needless to say, this is quite a lot of overhead per row and thus `.apply` is on a full `DataFrame` is slow.

In the below example, I have renamed some of the columns in the function calls since the example data was limited.

```
import sys
import time
import contextlib
import pandas as pd

@contextlib.contextmanager
def timethis(label):
    '''A context manager to time a bit of code.'''
    print('Timing', label, end=': ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    start = time.time()
    yield
    print('{:.4g} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))

... func1, func2, and func3 definitions...

def func4(s):
    if str(s['j']).isalpha() and str(s['f']).isdigit() and s['b'] is none:
        return s['f']

x = pd.DataFrame({'f': [3, 6, 29, 0, 360, 127, 130, 36, 960, 160, 106],
                  'j': 0,
                  'b': [None, None, None, None, 366, None, None, None, None, '205D', None]})
x = pd.concat(x for _ in range(100000))
y = x.copy()

x['a'] = x['b'].apply(lambda x: func1(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
x['c'] = x['j'].apply(lambda x: func2(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
x['e'] = x['f'].apply(lambda x: func3(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
with timethis('func4'):
    x['g'] = x.apply(func4, axis = 1)  # The lambda in your example was not needed

...

def vectorized_func4(df):
    '''Accept the whole DataFrame and not just a single row.'''
    j_isalpha = df['j'].astype(str).str.isalpha()
    f_isdigit = df['f'].astype(str).str.isdigit()
    b_None = df['b'].isnull()
    ret_col = df['f'].copy()
    keep_rows = j_isalpha & f_isdigit & b_None
    ret_col[~keep_rows] = None
    return ret_col

y['a'] = vectorized_func1(y['b'])
y['c'] = vectorized_func2(y['j'])
y['e'] = vectorized_func3(y['f'])
with timethis('vectorized_func4'):
    y['g'] = vectorized_func4(y)
```

The output:

```
Timing func4: 115.9 seconds
Timing vectorized_func4: 25.09 seconds
```

It turns out that for `func1`, `func2`, and `func3` it is a wash as far as performance when compared to the vectorized methods. `.apply` (and `.map` for that matter) on `Series` isn't so slow because there is no extra overhead per element. However, this does *not* mean that you should just use `.apply` when you have a `Series` and not investigate the vectorized built-in methods of the `Series` - more often than not you are likely to be able to do better than `apply`.

Here's how you might rewrite `func3` to be vectorized (I added timing statements so we could see what takes the most time).

```
def vectorized_func3(col):
    with timethis('fillna'):
        col = col.fillna('')
    with timethis('astype'):
        col = col.astype(str)
    with timethis('rest'):
        is_digit_string = col.str.isdigit()
        not_0_string = col != '0'
        keep_rows = is_digit_string & not_0_string
        col[~keep_rows] = None
    return col
```

Here is the timing compared to `func3`:

```
Timing func3: 8.302 seconds
Timing fillna: 0.006584 seconds
Timing astype: 9.445 seconds
Timing rest: 1.65 seconds
```

It takes a long time to just change the `dtype` of a `Series`, since a new `Series` must be created, and then each element gets cast.  Everything else is *blazing*. If you could change your algorithm to not require changing the datatype to `str`, or could simply store as `str` in the first place then the vectorized method would be *much* faster (especially `vectorized_func4`).

**Takeaway**

- Don't use `.apply` on a full `DataFrame` unless you absolutely must. If you think you must, go get a drink of coffee and think about it for ten minutes and try to think of a way to do it without `.apply`.
- Try not to use `.apply` on a `Series`, you can probably do better but it won't be as bad as on a full `DataFrame`.
- Try to come up with an algorithm that does not require constantly converting `dtype`.