# speed up this for loop - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, pandas

From my profiling, I could see this function takes more time to process. How do I speed up this code? My dataset has more than million records and this stopword list I have given here is just a sample - it actually contains 150 words.

```
def remove_if_name_v1(s):
    stopwords = ('western spring','western sprin','western spri','western spr','western sp','western s',
                 'grey lynn','grey lyn','grey ly','grey l')
    for word in stopwords:
        s = re.sub(r'(' + word + r'.*?|.*?)\b' + word + r'\b', r'\1', s.lower(), 1)
    return s.title()

test.new_name = test.old_name.apply(lambda x: remove_if_name_v2(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Seems the function is run for each row in the data frame and in each row, it runs the for loop as many times as the stop words. Is there any alternative approach?

What I am trying to do here is example, if the string contains "western spring road western spring", this function will return "western spring road".

Thanks.

Comment: I assume there are million 'test's  and 150 'stopwords'. In this case. you can precompile the regex of the 150 stopwords

Comment: Cool. How do I do that and apply here?

Comment: @ds_user can you post some more input/output samples? I am suspicious of your stopwords list. You try to substitute e.g. both `(western s.*?)` `(western spring.*?)` where the first case covers the second.

Comment: @ds_user, also I think `.*?` is redundant, and can be changed to just `.*`.

Comment: ok, here my intention on this `r'(' + word + r'.*?|.*?)\b' + word + r'\b'` snippet is to match with these cases "western spring road western spring" and also "kings road western spring". Here I don't want the stop words(city names) on these strings (street names). However keep it there if its the only the string in street name column also sometime street name will be similar to city name, so just remove city name but not street name.

Comment: And I have cases like "western spring road western spring" , "western spring road western sprin", "western spring road western spri", "western spring road western spri".

Comment: You may want to validate that the stop words do not contain special characters like '.,*,{},(),[]' as those can interfere with regex matching

Comment: @ds_user just so I'm clear, you want to take a list of cities, match strings like `<city> something else <city>`, and change them to `<city> something else`? And in addition to this, the string may be truncated at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick improvement is to put the stop words in a set.  When checking, multiple words it will result in a constant time O(1) lookup.

```
STOP_WORDS = {
    'western spring',
    'western sprin',
    'western spri',
    'western spr',
    'western sp',
    'western s',
    'grey lynn',
    'grey lyn',
    'grey ly',
    'grey l'
}

def find_first_stop(words):
    if len(words) == 0:
        return False
    joined = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    if joined in STOP_WORDS:
        return True
    return find_first_stop(words[:-len(words) - 1])

def remove_if_name_v1(s):
    if s in STOP_WORDS:
        return s

    words = []
    split_words = s.split(' ')
    for word in reversed(split_words):
        words.append(word)
        if find_first_stop(words):
            words = []
    return ' '.join(reversed(words))

old_name = pd.Series(['western spring road western spring', 'kings road western spring', 'western spring'])
new_name = old_name.apply(lambda x: remove_if_name_v1(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
print(new_name)
```

Output:

```
0    western spring road
1             kings road
2         western spring
dtype: object
```

Comment: Set is a good idea though, but this doesn't work as expected I suspect. Because this will result just "road" for the input "western spring road western spring". But what I am trying to do here is to just remove the second occurrence and bring everything before that.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want.  What is 's'?  It could be split into words and then pass through the filter one by one and be rejoined if it's not a stop word.

Comment: Problem with splitting approach is that we can't catch multiple words if we split them. 's' is a string, an example "western spring road western spring". If we split, we can't catch "western spring" on this.

Comment: I get it. It's a tricky problem because your stop words are phrases not just words.  I'm thinking of a fast solution and will come back with it.

Comment: @ds_user I wrote this algorithm which passes your test, but I'm not sure how fast it is.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for spending your time on it, I will check the speed. :)

Comment: Hello, I don't know whats happening in your script, haven't read it fully, but tried it with my data, its amazing, reduced hours of process to just 22 secs. Thanks a lot. :) [Though I am not using set, using just the tuple to preserve the order of stop words].

Answer (score 3):

You can combine and pre-compile the regex for a fairly big improvement.

```
stopwords = ('western spring',
             'western sprin',
             'western spri',
             'western spr',
             'western sp',
             'western s',
             'grey lynn',
             'grey lyn',
             'grey ly',
             'grey l')

pat = re.compile(r'(?P<repl>(?P<word>{stopwords}).*?|.*?)\b(?P=word)\b'.format(
                 stopwords='|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in stopwords)))

test.old_name.str.replace(pat, '\g<repl>')
```

Note the `(?P=word)` back-reference. I've also used `Series.str.replace` instead of `Series.apply`, which is slightly cleaner.

Comment: Not only is it cleaner, but likely `Series.str.replace` is faster than `apply` because it is vectorized.

Comment: @SethMMorton, in my experiments, it actually wasn't much faster. I think the implementation of `str.replace` is fairly close to `apply(lambda s: ...)`, since the regex engine is Python-side.

Comment: You need a list or tuple instead of set if you want the largest match

Comment: Is see. Well, at least it encourages the good pandas practice of using vectorized methods instead of hand-rolled functions when possible, since `apply` on a DataFrame is *definitely* slow.

Comment: To clarify @balki 's comment, the set is losing the order of the stopwords and so it's possible that a shorter word will be chosen if it ends up first. Using a list will correct that.

Comment: Yeah you are right @SethMMorton I am facing such issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080003/speed-up-python-apply-row-wise-functions?noredirect=1#comment77134177_45080003

Comment: @IgorRaush This is not working for this scenarios - strings like "kings road western spring". I mean if there is any other words apart from the stop words in the starting, I need that starting word. To make it clear, there are three cases, 1. western spring road western spring, 2. kings road western spring 3. western spring. And the outputs should be 1. western spring road 2.kings road 3.western spring.

Comment: @ds_user, I see. Then I don't think you can do it with one regex, since your case 2. doesn't satisfy the back-reference. You can design a second regex to cover that case.

Comment: Thats why I was using this initially - `re.sub(r'(' + word + r'.*?|.*?)\b' + word + r'\b', r'\1', s.lower(), 1)`

Comment: @IgorRaush How do I do that?